# CollectionView -> changing flow based on if logged in

Tags: ios, storyboard, uicollectionview

I have an App using a Story Board, CollectionViews and a NavigationController setup.  This works fine, but now I want to add in login.

So if the user is already logged in, I want to bypass the default behavior of going to the login screen.

What is the best way to change this flow?

thanks!
phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put logic in the viewDidAppear method of the navigation controller's root view controller that determines whether to show the login view or not. Present it modally with the animation set to no, and it will be the first thing the user sees.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if (!self.loggedIn) {
        UIViewController *login = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Login"];
        [self presentViewController:login animated:NO completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either tell the regular first view controller to instigate the segue in code when it appears (e.g. login view says: show next view if logged in).

Or something more radical in your app delegate, but I think it is safer to leave the flow as it is and just make it move on to the next screen and leave your storyboard untouched.